# shared preferences not being saved for login

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to use shared preferences for an android app after a user is logged in. In my app a user inputs his log in information which then is sent to an api which returns the user name and id if they are logged in.

I save the shared preferences data with this:

```
//set preferences
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("userName",userName);
editor.putString("userID",userID);
editor.commit();
```

I then try and access the data with this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("userName", null);
String restoredText2 = prefs.getString("userID", null);

Toast.makeText(this,  restoredText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Toast.makeText(this,  restoredText2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the preference using

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
```

in both setting and getting methods.

`getPreferences` is private for activity. When you use `getPreferences` method then it creates a preference with activity file name.

Answer (score 0):

**You Can use this class that i have made - its simple to use **

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class CommonUtil {

    public static String getStringPreference(Context context, String key) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key, null);
    }


    public static boolean setStringPreference(Context context, String key, String value) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putString(key, value).commit();
    }
}
```

**Usage in Code**

```
CommonUtil.setStringPreference(MyClass.this, "UID", userID);
CommonUtil.setStringPreference(MyClass.this, "PASS", pinNo);
```